# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' - EspeakNg

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using [`py-espeak-ng`](https://github.com/gooofy/py-espeak-ng) trying to run below code:

```
esng = ESpeakNG(voice='english-us')
esng.pitch = 32
esng.speed = 150
esng.say('Hello World!', sync=True)
```

But I get this error:

```
esng.say('Hello World!', sync=True)
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> 
  File "C:\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\espeakng\__init__.py", line 103, in say
    self._espeak_exe(args, sync=sync)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\espeakng\__init__.py", line 68, in _espeak_exe
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sub`enter code here`process.py", line 461, in list2cmdline
    needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
  TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: Your formatting is not good. You need to make sure the code part is set as code using the built in { } button. Also, this is mostly code. You need to add more information about what you are trying to do and what your expected output is.

Comment: is this `https://github.com/gooofy/py-espeak-ng` ?

Comment: i am trying to run one of definition given in  sample test in the above link. But getting the above error.

Comment: I had the same problem, could never solve it. I ended up just using the subprocess lib, as described here http://machakux.appspot.com/blog/44003/making_speech_with_python

Answer (score 0):

Python has two kind of strings: unicode and byte strings. In python 3, *normal* strings (`str`) are unicode strings, but some API require byte strings.

The error message:

> ```
> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
> ```

is an evidence that an API expected a byte string and got an unicode string. As the error is raised at `esng.say('Hello World!', sync=True)`, it means that `esng.say` expects a byte string.

You should just write:

```
esng.say('Hello World!'.encode(), sync=True)
```

Comment: This gives the error: "AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'"

Comment: @ReedJones: In Python 3.x the expression `'Hello World!'.encode()` cannot raise that error.

Comment: the problem is in the espeak library, at some point it is calling subprocess.Popen, and there is a bad string there

Comment: (the "say" function already calls encode on the str argument anyway) 
txte = txt.encode('utf8')

Comment: If the problem is inside the library I can nothing for you: I do not use nor know it. Looks like I should delete this no-answer :-( ...